# Style Checkbox after Label with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a Label and an Checkbox Input after it [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/1yfv5pne/21/):

```
<label for="accept">Accept</label>
<input id="accept" type="checkbox">
```

I need to style the checkbox so I tried the following:

```
<label for="accept">Accept</label>
<input id="accept" type="checkbox">
```

In this case the checkbox stops working and I am able to style it.

Then I swapped the position of Label and Checkbox Input:

```
<input id="accept" type="checkbox">
<label for="accept">Accept</label>
```

In this case it is working, styled, but the input and label appear in same line.

I would like to style the checkbox input and have the label and checkbox in different lines.

The CSS is the following:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

label::before, label::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

label::before{
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  left: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}

label::after {
  height: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 4px;
  top: 7px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
  content: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: rgb(59, 153, 252) auto 5px;
}
```

**Note:** On my examples I also wasn't able to vertically align the checkbox with the label.

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Comment: @Paulie_D I would like to change the checkbox border, background color and icon

Comment: @cloned I have read and tried the code on that question before but wasn't able to make it work with checkbox on line after label

Comment: Change icon? What icon?

Comment: @Paulie_D Fair enough ... You are right. I did tried to make it work but I didn't include those attempts on my question. But now I just added the code and also a JSFiddle example. Does it help?

Comment: don't add a jsfiddle link, create a working snippet in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
form input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

form .checkicon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

form .checkicon::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

form .checkicon::after {
  height: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 3px;
  top:3px
}

form input[type="checkbox"] + .checkicon::after {
  content: none;
}

form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkicon::after {
  content: "";
}

form input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .checkicon::before {
  outline: rgb(59, 153, 252) auto 5px;
}

div label {
  display: block;
}

h4 { margin: 12px 0; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="accept1" type="checkbox">
   <label class="checkicon" for="accept1"></label>
  <label>Accept</label>
</form>
```

this is it ! hope this help!

Comment: I need the label text to be before the check box. So the first line would have the label text and the second line would have the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/dh72qb5f/12/

HTML

```
<div>
  <label for="accept1">
  <input id="accept1" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
  Accept
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {  
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div{
  position: relative;
}
label {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.checkbox-custom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.checkbox-custom::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #ccc;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid #ffffff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: I need the label text to be in a different line than the checkbox. And the label should be in the first line.